# PHP - replace in string from a word to another

Tags: php

I have a string in a variable, for example:

```
$example1 = "Received: from example.host.com (example.host.com [1.2.3.4]) by received.host.com (Postfix) with ESMTP id 123456789ABCD for ; Tue, 3 Apr 2018 12:33:59 +0200 (CEST)"

$example2 = "Received: from another.example.org (unknown [22.33.44.55]) by another.received.org (Postfix) with ESMTP id 987654321FEDC for ; Tue, 3 Apr 2018 12:35:15 +0200 (CEST)"
```

What I would like to replace everything between `by` and `for` with pattern `...`

So **example1** should be:

```
"Received: from example.host.com (example.host.com [1.2.3.4]) by ... for ; Tue, 3 Apr 2018 12:33:59 +0200 (CEST)"
```

And **example2** should be:

```
"Received: from another.example.org (unknown [22.33.44.55]) by ... for ; Tue, 3 Apr 2018 12:35:15 +0200 (CEST)"
```

The only problem is (because of mail haders) that everything between "by" and "for" could be changed, it will never be the same. Everything else in the examples must remain the same.

Comment: Read up on regular expressions, [preg_replace()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) and make some attempts. If you get stuck, come back and show us what you've tried.

Comment: `\bby\b.*?\bfor\b` with `preg_replace` should be a good starting point. http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php

Comment: What if the string contained by and for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
$string = "Received: from another.example.org (unknown [22.33.44.55]) by another.received.org (Postfix) with ESMTP id 987654321FEDC for ; Tue, 3 Apr 2018 12:35:15 +0200 (CEST)";
$x = strpos($string,'by');
$y = strpos($string,'for');
echo substr($string, 0, $x+2)."...".substr($string, $y);
?>
```

Comment: Don't forget to mention that the OP can't have hosts that contain the words `by` or `for` since that will mess this script up.

Comment: Consider if the string had `form` or `bytes` in it.

Comment: Well, I think it will be good if I modify it a bit:$x = strpos($string,' by ');
$y = strpos($string,' for '); Then if the hostname contains "by" and/or "for" it will work too. Look for the space before and after the " by " and " for " I think this is better then play with regexps.

Answer (score -1):

Use example

```
<?php
echo str_replace("world","Peter","Hello world!");
?>
```

Comment: The OP wants to replace all content between two words.

Comment: ...and the OP should at least make an attempt before expecting to get answers since SO isn't a free coding service.

Comment: You _really_ need to start paying attention to what the issue/question actually is. This isn't the first answer you've posted today that's missing the point.